# Running Spring Boot "Hello World" on Java 11?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-module, java-11

I'm getting started with Spring Boot. I'm doing the [example Hello World application from the official getting started page](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/). When I get to the point that I have my `HelloController` and my `Application` and I'd like to run it with `./gradlew build && java -jar build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar`, I get the exception

```
2018-12-01 18:04:26.324 ERROR 4581 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1420) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet (in unnamed module @0x2f1f99d1) cannot access class javax.annotation.security.DeclareRoles (in module java.annotation) because module java.annotation does not export javax.annotation.security to unnamed module @0x2f1f99d1
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadClassAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:258) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:88) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat$FixContextListener.lifecycleEvent(Tomcat.java:973) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        ... 6 common frames omitted

2018-12-01 18:04:26.328 ERROR 4581 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:366) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at hello.Application.main(Application.java:14) ~[classes!/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1420) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:950) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet (in unnamed module @0x2f1f99d1) cannot access class javax.annotation.security.DeclareRoles (in module java.annotation) because module java.annotation does not export javax.annotation.security to unnamed module @0x2f1f99d1
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadClassAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:258) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:88) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat$FixContextListener.lifecycleEvent(Tomcat.java:973) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        ... 6 common frames omitted

2018-12-01 18:04:26.329  INFO 4581 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-12-01 18:04:26.333  WARN 4581 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2018-12-01 18:04:26.349  INFO 4581 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-12-01 18:04:26.356 ERROR 4581 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at hello.Application.main(Application.java:14) ~[classes!/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:366) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:950) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1420) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:950) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet (in unnamed module @0x2f1f99d1) cannot access class javax.annotation.security.DeclareRoles (in module java.annotation) because module java.annotation does not export javax.annotation.security to unnamed module @0x2f1f99d1
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadClassAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:258) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:88) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat$FixContextListener.lifecycleEvent(Tomcat.java:973) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        ... 6 common frames omitted
```

I guess the `because module java.annotation does not export javax.annotation.security to unnamed module @0x2f1f99d1`, and the fact that I'm trying to run this on Java 11 means that something should be done to let the modules see each other, but what exactly?

Setting `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` to `11` (as opposed to `1.8` from the guide) in `build.gradle` didn't help. And neither did setting the classpath to `"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.0.RELEASE"`.

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

To start off, you can use the VM arg

```
--add-exports java.annotation/javax.annotation.security=ALL-UNNAMED
```

But to be futuristic, you should actually look into the implementation of the class `org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet` as to why it's accessing the class from `java.annotation` module `javax.annotation.security.DeclareRoles`.

In the module system, you can look into why `org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet` is getting resolved into the *classpath* since if it would've been on the *modulepath* you wouldn't have seen the error. Maybe some dependency bringing it in directly/transitively is not placed on the module path.

Comment: This shouldn't be needed. The question needs to be expanded to explain where the java.annotation is coming from. The version in Java EE is an automatic module so it exports all packages, including javax.annotation.security.

Answer (score 1):

you use spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE version but this version support java 9 and java 10 versions. Spring Boot 2.1.0.M2 support java 11. Check spring version.

[Spring Boot with Java 9 and above](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-with-Java-9-and-above)

Comment: While I'm aware, that older version of Spring Boot didn't support Java 11, setting the version to `2.1.0.RELEASE` didn't help either.